# Difference between [undefined × 2] and [undefined, undefined] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of,

> Note: this implies an array of 7 empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values

What does it mean?

```
const foo = Array(2)
undefined
const bar = [undefined, undefined]
undefined
foo[0] === bar[0]
true
foo
[undefined × 2]
bar
[undefined, undefined]
```

What's the difference between them? Is there any use case that I can only use one but not the other?

Comment: Try doing `'0' in foo` vs `'0' in bar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo` has two empty slots not filled with anything (which is resolved to `undefined` in console). `bar` is filled with the value of `undefined`.

So, for example `Array.prototype.map` is defined to only work when values are set:

```
foo.map(() => console.log('test'))
// nothing

bar.map(() => console.log('test'))
// test
// test
```

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting question.

when you do `const foo = Array(2)`; it creates an Array with nothing in it, but length is 2. So `foo.length === 2` (true).

But you know even `foo[0] === undefined` (true), actaully `foo[100] === undefined` (true), so there is really 'nothing' inside the Array. It is why it is different with [undefined, undefined]